# Angular How can i get my array from localStorage JSON

Tags: angular, typescript

This is JSON I have saved in my localStorage:

```
{
   "calculatorInfo":{
      "gender":"F",
      "name":"test",
      "surname":"test"
   },
   "contactInfo":{
      "email":"fvreferf@gmail.com",
      "phone":"568553322"
   },
   "underageChildInfo":[
      {
         "gender":"F",
         "name":"test1",
         "surname":"test2"
      },
      {
         "gender":"F",
         "name":"test3",
         "surname":"test"
      }
   ]
}
```

I am getting this data and saving it to my object like this:
but when I am trying to save my array it says undefined.

How can I save my array in this object?

```
personalInfo: any;

    this.data = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('policy'));
    
       get info(): any {
         return this.personalInfo = {
            personalInfoId: 0,
            insurerInfo: {
               firstName:  this.data.calculatorInfo.name,
               lastName : this.data.calculatorInfo.surname,
               email: this.data.contactInfo.email
            },
            legalHeir:true,
            underageChildInfo: [
            {
              firstName: this.data.underageChildInfo.name
            }
            ]
          }
       }
```

Comment: Can you share the whole component file. It seems you have initialised the array.

Comment: Did you use `JSON. stringify() ` when setting the value in the local storage?

Comment: @Apoorva Chikara hi, i edited my question.

Comment: @Rukshan Jayasekara hi yes i did

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of

```
underageChildInfo: [
    {
        firstName: this.data.underageChildInfo.name
    }
]
```

you can do:

```
underageChildInfo: this.data.underageChildInfo
```

and if you only want to return the name

```
underageChildInfo: this.data.underageChildInfo.map(i => ({ firstName: i.name }))
```

I hope this works.. didn't test it!

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer.
i get this error Operator '>' cannot be applied to types 'number' and '{ firstName: any; }'.ts(2365)

Comment: my fault (java vs javascript): you have to use '=>' instead of '->'. I updated my code.

Comment: That still won't work if you're expecting an array of objects. You need to do `.map(i => ({ firstName: i.name}));`..

Comment: @HereticMonkey You are absolutly right. Strange.. I cannot remember I've ever had this issue in typescript. Good to know.

Answer (score 1):

The error is here

```js
underageChildInfo: [
    {
        firstName: this.data.underageChildInfo.name
    }
]
```

Map the `firstName` from `this.data.underageChildInfo` to `underageChildInfo`:

```js
underageChildInfo: this.data.underageChildInfo
    .map(val => ({ firstName: val.name }))
```

Comment: hi! thanks for the answer! Operator '>' cannot be applied to types 'number' and '{ firstName: any; }'.ts(2365)
i get this error

Comment: @user487322225, he had a typo. It should be `val => ({ firstName: val.name })`

Answer (score 0):

the issue in the code specifically on this snippet

```
underageChildInfo: [
            {
              firstName: this.data.underageChildInfo.name
            }
            ]
```

so instead if this sniipt i suggetes to replace it with this following code block :

```
underageChildInfo:this.data.underageChildInfo.map((item) => {
      return { firstName: item.name };
    })
```